# Does actualism imply moral nihilism?

Tags: ethics, possible-worlds

Actualism is the view that only the actual is possible. Moral nihilism is the belief in the nonexistence of morality. My question is, does actualism imply moral nihilism? At least in my case, the reason I don't believe in morality, is because I believe only the actual is possible. Morality, to me, seems a hypothetical assertion, like "X is morally right because if X happened, the world would have more pleasure/utility". But I don't believe in hypotheticals. My question really is, does actualism imply moral nihilism? Or is it possible to consistently be both an actualist and a believer of the existence of morality?

Comment: so do you have values, and how are they different from moral imperatives? just curious, idc if you're a moral nihilist (ceteris paribus)

Comment: It's a whole paradigm shift but one can still have moral feelings that "things are what they are but would have been preferable otherwise", which is the basics of moral thinking. "John punched me in the face, it couldn't have been otherwise but i want to take the necessary steps so that it does not happen again, for i don't like being punched". Restorative justice, for example, is a moral stance compatible with actualism focusing on avoiding the reiteration of a bad outcome in the future by actually changing the material living conditions of the culprit.

Comment: You unreferenced definition of actualism is confused, some open-minded actualists don't reject possibilities which are not actual as counterfactuals. With the right view of actualism which says only actual entities exist, one cannot derive moral nihilism logically since either virtue or categorical imperative may be actual even if you're unable to calculate future actualized utilities if-then-ism-ly. Perhaps you mean necessitarianism instead of actualism, but even necessitarianism doesn't entail moral nihilism, on the contrary, wherefrom ethics may well be required or at least preferred...

Comment: No. An actualist can be a moral realist, i.e. believe in moral facts. In that case, morality is not a hypothetical assertion, that X is morally right is an actual fact (when it is). If one believes in God, for example, it is a fact because God actually commanded it to be right, but there are secular forms of moral realism as well, see [SEP, Moral Realism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-realism/). Your argument does suggest that actualism may be incompatible with some forms of [utilitarianism](https://iep.utm.edu/util-a-r/) that judge morality of actions by their hypothetical effects.

Comment: Actualism and moral nihilism are separate philosophical positions: one deals with what exists (actualism), and the other deals with the nature of morality (moral nihilism). Being an actualist doesn't automatically make you a moral nihilist. They operate in different philosophical domains, and it's possible to be an actualist while still believing in some form of morality. Therefore, actualism does not necessarily imply moral nihilism.